# Timeout on angularjs call

Tags: angularjs, json, timeout, ui-grid

I'm sure this has been asked numerous times, but I'm ... can't find it. It's 10:30pm here and I've just got to leave this with you guys!

Essentially, I've got two calls to json server methods - update data and get new totals. Logically, update data is called first, sends a notification via $emit which gets the new totals. Unfortunately, when I put breakpoints on the server controller,  GetAlertTotals is called before SetAlertRead, so the wrong data is returned.

The 'totals' code is in another controller, hence the $emit/publish/subscribe:

```
$scope.$on('RefreshUnreadItemsCounter', function () {
    $scope.alertCount = $scope.GetAlertCount();
    $scope.alertTotals = $scope.GetAlertTotals();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

The data is in a uiGrid, with the following (partial) definition:

```
    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);

    $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
        var authorisationToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

        row.entity.AlertSeen = true;
        $scope.message = row.entity.Message;
        $http({
            url: '/Alerts/SetAlertRead',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            method: 'POST',
            data: { rowId: row.entity.UserAlertsId },
            headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': authorisationToken }
        });
        $scope.$emit('RefreshUnreadItemsCounter');
    });
```

The user clicks on a row to display the data associated with the row and 'reads' it, triggering the data update via the json call (`/Alert/SetAlertRead`). I'm presuming that I put a timeout before the $emit call, to give the promise time to execute the json call, but I'm not sure how.

Please help! I'll need as much code as possible if you wouldn't mind! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you call `$scope.$emit('RefreshUnreadItemsCounter');` immediately without giving chance to $http request to be resolved or rejected. You can use `finally()` to cover both cases, or treat resolve and reject cases separately using `then(successFunction, errorFunction)`. Try to change your code to:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
$scope.gridApi = gridApi;
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);

$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
    var authorisationToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    row.entity.AlertSeen = true;
    $scope.message = row.entity.Message;
    $http({
        url: '/Alerts/SetAlertRead',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: 'POST',
        data: { rowId: row.entity.UserAlertsId },
        headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': authorisationToken }
    }).then(function (response) {
      $scope.$emit('RefreshUnreadItemsCounter');
    }, function (error) {
      // case of rejected promise
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Andriy - that fixed the issue with perfect clarity. I can't upvote your answer because I haven't asked enough questions yet... I've only been registered two years...